# JAVA TLS 1.2 downgrade to TLS 1.0 sometimes error

Tags: java, iis, ssl, nginx

I have TLS client writen in JAVA. When i set

```
sslContext = TLS1.2
and enabled protocols to SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLS1.2
```

it works fine with almost all servers. Client start handshake with TLSv1.2. If server can only TLSv1, connection downgrades to TLSv1 during handshake. 
But! We use about 15 such TLSv1 services and 4 of them fails to downgrade. Servers are all different:

Microsoft-IIS/7.5, nginx, IBM_HTTP_SERVER, SQLAnywhere.

Errors like this:

```
SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message  X2
handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Invalid Padding length: 139
javaException : Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
```

If i set enabled protocols to TLSv1, that servers works fine. But i want set sslContext and enabled protocols to be compatible with all services and preferably work with TLSv1.2

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i want set sslContext and enabled protocols to be compatible with all services and preferably work with TLSv1.2

First, there are enough servers out there which don't do TLS 1.2 but the best they can do is TLS 1.0 (and some even only SSL 3.0). A proper implementation of the TLS stack would in this case simply send a TLS 1.0 reply and thus enforcing the connection to be TLS 1.0 which is supported in your client. Forcing these servers to TLS 1.2 will not work because they don't implement it. All you could do is replace the servers with newer implementations.

And then there are several implementations out there which incorrectly implement the protocol. Some of these simply close the connection if you send a TLS 1.2 ClientHello or use some TLS extensions they never heard of. If you can not replace these servers you have to communicate with them in a way they will understand, like speaking only TLS 1.0 etc. Browsers already deal with this rotten servers by slowly downgrading the connection, i.e. if TLS 1.2 causes a handshake failure they will try again with TLS 1.0 etc. Often browsers even have hard coded a list of servers which are too rotten to even play nice after trying simple downgrads and which need to have special ciphers or something like this.

Comment: Yes we work with many services that supports TLSv1 only. And we can't change it's implementation - they not ours. Most of them downgrades to TLSv1 successfully during handshake. But work like browser is not good case, because every time we must send at least 2 request instead of 1. Our client is part of billing system and we want to send only successfull requests.

Comment: Maybe java can somehow handshake with such rotten servers?

Comment: Althouth i think it's seems not possible. :)

Comment: @cynepnaxa: You already know that it works if you explicitly set the connection to TLSv1. So what you must do is to either attempt to automatically downgrade or to have pre-defined site-specific configurations in your program to work around such broken servers.

Comment: And i don't understand - "hard coded a list of servers' - it means list of IP adresses and names?

Comment: @cynepnaxa: since it is usually the name you use to connect to a site it would probably be best to make special configurations per name.